# Expressing Audit functionality with JPA annotations

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I'm in the middle of fumbling around with JPA. I've so far successfully created an entity representing the user data and a stateless bean for the access to the user data.

The data the users can work on is like this ([SQLFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f92b)):

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  email character varying(128) NOT NULL,
  data character varying(128) NOT NULL,
  lastchange timestamp NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT email_data PRIMARY KEY (email,data)
);
```

The idea is to save the unaltered, current version for all users with an empty `email` key. Then, when a user alters the data and creates an auditable version, the `email` field is filled with the users email. This way, each user can alter their copy of the data. The merging is a problem for a later date and not part of my question.

Now, I have the entities already in place. I created a stateless bean to load/save/find the data records by using the EntityManager. The logic to load the user specific version first, then load the unaltered version if the user has no user specific version still eludes me.

Consider this part of the bean:

```
@Stateless
public class DataBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "authPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<DataEntry> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<DataEntry> query = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM data d", DataEntry.class);
        List<DataEntry> list = query.getResultList();
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    ...
}
```

How do I inject the user information into this class? I need to get the data for the current user first, then get the data for all users if there's no user-specific data available.

Comment: "select * from data" is not JPQL.

Comment: I've altered the code.

Comment: The query you are issuing gives you back all Data.  If you are after only data for a particular email, shouldn't you pass in that email and query for it?  "where d.email is null or d.email = :email"?  This too might not be what you want, since data will not be unique.  But I don't understand why you have data as part of the PK - shouldn't it just be email address?  Data implies something that is changing, and a primary key value should never change.  using a sequence value for the PK is recommended instead.

Comment: You're right. The "Data" in the query is what the users are able to change. I could introduce an artificial primary key, then create a unique composite constraint on these two fields, and the problem would still be the same, as I still need to select the data based on the email that I do not have at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard EJB authentication. Then you can call `SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` in your session bean to get a user ID. Use this user ID to query the database.

In this case you have to add another column to your table (containing the user ID), if the authentication user ID does not equal the email address.

Far simpler (but less elegant) is to add the email address to the arguments of your EJB service method: Just make it part of the public API.